# QtWebEngineQuick didnt show html content from resource file

Tags: qt, qml, qtwebengine, qt6, qtwebenginequick

I want to compile and run [WebEngine Recipe Browser](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwebengine-webenginequick-recipebrowser-example.html) Example with `Qt-6.2.3` or `Qt_6_4_0` but I get this **error**:

```
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
qt.webenginecontext: 

GLImplementation: desktop
Surface Type: OpenGL
Surface Profile: CompatibilityProfile
Surface Version: 4.6
Using Default SG Backend: yes
Using Software Dynamic GL: no
Using Angle: no

Init Parameters:
  *  application-name recipebrowser 
  *  browser-subprocess-path /home/parisa/Applications/Qt/6.2.3/gcc_64/libexec/QtWebEngineProcess 
  *  create-default-gl-context  
  *  disable-features DnsOverHttpsUpgrade,ConsolidatedMovementXY,InstalledApp,BackgroundFetch,WebOTP,WebPayments,WebUSB,PictureInPicture 
  *  disable-setuid-sandbox  
  *  disable-speech-api  
  *  enable-features NetworkServiceInProcess,TracingServiceInProcess 
  *  enable-threaded-compositing  
  *  gpu-preferences UAAAAAAAAAAoAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABgAAAAAAAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAA= 
  *  in-process-gpu  
  *  use-gl desktop
```

and I see this result:

[image]

**web pages (html content ) can't load from qrc (Resource file).**

But as I Build and Run this example in `Qt-5.15.2` it runs correctly.

[image]

The only difference between these two versions and examples is that `Qt-5.15.2` uses `QtWebEngine` but in `Qt-6.2.3` or `Qt_6_4_0` they use `QtWebEngineQuick`.

I dont know how should I fix this issue and use `QtWebEngineQuick`.

I test `QtWebEngineQuick` and this issue will happen when I want to load any HTML file (even simple) from Resource , but if I choose url from web like `https://stackoverflow.com` it works correctly.

for example, if I want to Run this Example I got that Error!

**in main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtWebEngineQuick/qtwebenginequickglobal.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif
    QtWebEngineQuick::initialize();

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**in main.qml**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtWebEngine

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    WebEngineView {
        id: webView
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "qrc:/index.html"
    }
}
```

**in index.html**

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>Hello World<h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

**error output picture:**

[image]

**I use Ubuntu 20.04 and NVIDIA 470 GPU.**
**I don't understand why this happens and how can I fix it.**

Comment: Why don't you use a relative reference. Since both `main.qml` and `index.html` are at the same hierarchy. Then you should only need to specify `url: "index.html"`

Comment: @StephenQuan Thanks for your comment but It didnt work, the problem is to load the pages from the file.
I also tested "`url: "index.html"` too, but it didn't matter
I have trouble even running Qt example ( [WebEngine Recipe Browser](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwebengine-webenginequick-recipebrowser-example.html)) and the pages are not loaded

Comment: @Parisa.H.R try "qrc:///..." I did not test it but just a blind guess

Comment: @SoheilArmin Thanks for your comment but It didn't work, I try `"qrc:///index.html"`, `"index.html"` and `"qrc:/index.html"` but in all of them, they can't load files.  I have trouble even running the Qt example ( [WebEngine Recipe Browser](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwebengine-webenginequick-recipebrowser-example.html)) and pages are not loading in that example, it uses `"qrc:///pages/pizza.html"`